# Can i stop/cancel gparted resize in middle of move to the right?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gparted

I wanted to extend my `/` partition from 20GB to 100GB by taking 80GB from the `/home` partition.

- My `/` is on `sda3`
- My /home is on `sda5`

So I used `gparted` and moved the front of `sda5` right to subtract the 80GB, but i didn't know it would move all of my `sda5` data 80gb ahead, and that this process would take 10hours.

I have a weak internet connection to my server and if the `ssh` connection gets dropped all the data could potentially get lost as I am doing this in rescue mode using `qemu-kvm` and forgot to start `screen` before starting this process.

*Is there any way to cancel the resize of my 2TB drive without it being corrupted?*

Because in the meantime, I figured out it would have been much faster if I moved `sda3` to the end of the disk after shrinking `sda5` by 80GB.

EDIT: The process is completed. I used repytr to move the process from SSH to screen and god it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

From the data we've been given, I'm assuming the following:

- You did not take a 10h system backup before you started
- You have a weak internet connection and the ssh session *might be lost*

So under the current situation, the best thing to do is:

- start a ping to the host so the connection is kept alive
- Wait for 10 hours

Depending on the outcome, you just:

- reboot your system and everything is fine
- have the service provider / DCOps / ... reboot the host after they've confirmed there is no high load on the disks any more.

If you would have used `parted` instead of `gparted` to do the resize, you could have stopped the resize as it does the resize by moving the last allocated blocks first and then goes to the front and only updates the partition table if everything went fine.

***However* as you're using the GUI, the results are *unpredictable*, so the best thing to do now is wait...**

<sub>**Note:** Next time, take a system backup before doing things like this and use the command line instead of the GUI, which forces you to think before doing....</sub>

Comment: The process is completed. I used repytr to move the process from SSH to screen and god it worked fine.

Comment: @Harsh *I'm happy for you...*  **:-)** As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby can you explain more why the gui is less predictable then the tui for cancelling?  Do they actually operate differently underneath?

Comment: That would be worth a question all by itself @rrauenza.  Just post one and copy - paste a link to this question to provide context...